# maximum capacity factors of combined cycle gas power plants

Tags: power, gas

What is the maximum annual capacity factor that can be expected of a CCGT plant? I see in US in 2015 the *average* was about [0.56](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=25652), but can it be higher? I guess it needs some time for maintenance but I don't know how much. Any guidance on where I can get such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on the link you provided.  Look at the middle graph, titled "Distribution of annual capacity factors for natural gas combined-cycle plants (2005, 2015)" and look at the Y axis, ranging from 0-10% up to 90-100%.  You can see that there were about 20 plants with a CF greater than 90% in 2015, and about 70 plants with a CF less than 10% that same year.